# Изображение весом в 0,5 МБ при отрисовке в приложении занимает 20 МБ оперативки. Как это исправить?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

В моем Xamarin-приложении под Android выводится фотография. Я использую MVVM.

### Устройство приложения

Во `ViewModel` я создал свойство, в котором находится путь к изображению:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        // Фото берется с сайта
        ImageSource = "http://aspzodiak1-001-site1.etempurl.com/21.png";
    }
    // Путь к фото
    public string ImageSource { get; }
}
```

Во `View` я через `Binding` присваиваю путь изображению (`ViewModel` указана для `View` в качестве `BindingContext`):

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="NataliasShopAdmin.View">
<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
```

### Результат

Запуск приложения на телефоне (Android 7.1) ****без**** изображения: приложение весит **60** МБ оперативки.
Запуск приложения ***с*** изображением - весит **83** МБ оперативки.

Как так? Почему изображение, которое весит 0,5 МБ занимает так много оперативной памяти?

### Что я пытался

*Если изменить размер `<Image />`, то толку не будет - изображение все равно будет занимать 20 МБ оперативной памяти.
И дело не в том, что оно берется с интернета - точно такой же результат получается и при встраивании изображения в приложение (указываю в качестве пути `drawable`).

Как исправить эту проблему?

### Обновлено

1. Библиотека `FFImageLoading` не решает проблему;
2. Специально, чтобы проверить, установил Android Studio. Загрузил эту же фотку в проект. Вставил 10 изображений - о чудо, приложение потребляет всего 93 МБ оперативки. Xamarin "болеет" видимо.

Comment: 83 МБ - это что, оперативная память, занятая приложением? Почему это представляет проблему? 20 МБ - довольно небольшой объем.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, да, оперативки (я обновил пост). 20 МБ на одну картинку. А картинок, то загружаться может и 10. И тогда приложение занимает по 300 МБ оперативки и просто крашится. Такой объем потребляемой памяти - это огромная проблема.

Comment: Это примерно как с программой запакованной в архив. 0.5Мб - это сжатое изображение, оно не может сразу показываться. Чтобы показать изображение нужно его сначала разжать, от этого и получается 20Мб.

Comment: используйте FFImageLoading. Память сэкономит. Но вот от лагов не избавит. Вам всеравно нужна будет эта библиотека, так как она довольно мощная. И решает кучу проблем, так как нативный xamarin image тормознутый и глюкавый.  И жрущий память особенно если он в listview

Comment: @ГеннадийП, допустим так. Но скажите, пожалуйста, каким образом приложения могут показывать по 20 изображений (все они видны на экране) и при этом занимать объем оперативки всего лишь по 130 МБ, когда у меня от показа 4 изображений, приложение занимает столько же?

Comment: @zodiak1  натив android работает лучше чем xamarin.  Работая с xamarin готовьтесь к тому что там большие проблемы с оптимизацией.  да вы можете написать довольно неплохое приложение если там только окна ввода и label. Добавление много графики приведет к лагам.

Comment: @zodiak1 У меня был опыт работы на java(натив) с android и с xamarin и работа с изображениями. Где их обьем заранее неизвестен.  Так вот.  с нативом я вообще не парился с изображениями. Все работало изначально. А вот с xamarin.. я получал то утечку памяти. То лаги с которыми я до конца и не знаю как избавиться.  Мой опыт показыват что xamarin только для легких бизнес приложений.  Где картинки должны быть заранее заданного размера и оптимизированы.  и занимать 5-10 кb. Что то больше уже начинается боль.

Comment: @Manul74, спасибо вам за совет. Попробую применить FFImage

Comment: @zodiak1 хочу предупредить. что FFimage не так чтобы сэкономит память, не в том что картинки будут меньше. Он их будет быстрей выгружать из памяти. Что сэкономит накапливание памяти. Там есть куча настроек, которыми вы сможете регулировать кеш и освобождение памяти.

Comment: `Как исправить эту проблему?` Я думаю, что это не проблема. А вы пробовали 2 разных изображения? У верено, что будет точно не +40. Скорее всего еще библиотека подгружается для работы с картинками.

Comment: @aepot, конечно пробовал. Результат тот же, а иногда и хуже...

Comment: То есть 10 картинок съедают +200 МБ? А 50 картинок - 1 ГБ оперативы? Ну тогда да, это проблема.

Comment: У вас там огромное разрешение у изображение. Можно спокойно уменьшить его раза в 2 или 4 по ширине и высоте. Что даст снижение веса в 4 или 16 раз соответственно.

Comment: Ну, изображение в примере по формату довольно большое для мобилы, может его как-то уменьшить на стороне сервера? Вы открываете изображения со своего сервера, или с любого?

Comment: @КириллМалышев, нет, так не работает) Уменьшил изображение в раз 5 - тот же результат.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, в своем приложении я прошу пользователя выбрать его фото из галереи. Уменьшать пользователь свое фото не будет (естественно =) ). А с сервера я качал для примера. Мне нужно, чтобы фото, какое оно есть, спокойно открывалось в приложении и не занимало памяти как 12 изображений.

Comment: Не держите их все в памяти разом, если нужны миниатюры - держите их в памяти как массив Bitmap'ов. Максимум можно держать соседние.